# Tricky converse question

Tags: logic

Could someone please explain why the converse of the false statement

> $x \in \{\frac{a}{b} \ | \ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\} \implies x \in \mathbb{Q} \ $

is

> $\ x \notin \{\frac{a}{b} \ | \ a,b\notin \mathbb{Z}\} \implies x \in \mathbb{Q}$

and also why the converse of

> $a > 0$ and $a^2<0 \implies a \leqslant -1 \ $

is

> $\ a \leqslant -1 \implies a > 0$ or $a^2<0$ ?

Comment: The [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) of $P \to Q$ is $Q \to P$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why this deserves a negative rating - could those rating this down please explain how I could improve the question at least

Comment: I am aware of that definition Mauro, however here P and Q have not simply swapped.

Comment: You have two different questions that run on in a way that makes them difficult to tell apart.  I suggest you keep your post focused to a single question.

Comment: You mean the answers are wrong?

Comment: They aren't my answers. I found them in a online textbook along with the questions and I have been confused as to where they are getting this from. They seem to go against what I thought the converse meant.

Comment: They're from here http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~tfylam/Math217/proofs01-sol.pdf

Comment: See page 3 : "The **converse** of $P \Rightarrow Q$ is $Q \Rightarrow P$."

Comment: I understand the definition Mauro, but underneath that you'll notice one of the above examples with its 'answer'

Comment: I suppose that in Ex.1.3(b) there is a typo, "mixing" part of converse with contrapositive : both are wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46480/discussion-between-wrb98-and-mauro-allegranza).

Answer (score 2):

For the converse of an implication, switch the hypothesis and the conclusion.

The converse of 
$$x \in \left\{\frac{a}{b} \ | \ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\right\} \implies x \in \mathbb{Q} $$
is
$$x \in \mathbb{Q} \implies  \ x \in \left\{\frac{a}{b} \ | \ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\right\} .$$

The converse of 
$$(a > 0 \text{ and } a^2<0) \implies a \leqslant -1 $$
is
$$a \leqslant -1 \implies (a > 0 \text{ and } a^2<0). $$

The supposed converses given are not converses nor inverses nor contrapositives of the initial implications.

Answer (score 1):

This question is referring to the following problems in [these notes](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~tfylam/Math217/proofs01-sol.pdf):

- Problem 1.3(b) (with "$x$" in place of "$a$"), and
- Problem 1.5(i).

In each case, the notes have what the OP has written. So the OP's confusion is understandable.

*These problems are simply wrong*.

Comment: In 1.3(b), the "and" and "or" were simply switched between the converse and the contrapositive.

I find the error in 1.5(i) indefensible.